# Bad screen resolution after updating to 18.04

Tags: 18.04, display, display-resolution, xrandr

I updated to Beaver today (from 17.10).

Everything else seems to be working fine. Except for my display resolution.
It defaults to `940x540` and I can't change it via `Settings > Display`. Needless to say my laptop has a screen supporting a resolution up to `1920x1080`. I did manage to change it using `xrandr` and am persisting the changes using    `~/.xprofile`

But still the Log In screen is displayed in a crappy resolution of `940x540`. Any Ideas on how to fix it?

**FYI:**

- My display drivers are working just fine. (`nvidia-390`)
- I've tried reinstalling display drivers.

Comment: Type `cat /etc/default/grub | grep LINUX` does `nomodeset` show up?

Comment: It outputs
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true`